# Can't align JKabel

Tags: alignment, jlabel

Well, I have this code:

```
  static class things implements ActionListener {        
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {     
        JFrame frame4 = new JFrame("More things");
        frame4.setVisible(true);
        frame4.setResizable(true);
        frame4.setSize(1366,730);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>One thing more</html>");
        label.setVerticalAlignment(SwingConstants.BOTTOM);
        label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
        panel.add(label); 
        frame4.add(panel);

      }
    }
```

But when I run it, the JLabel with the Vertical/horizontal alignment isn't align, why?

Answer (score 0):

That happens because of `LayoutManager`. Read more about using different [`LayoutManager`'s](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html)

1)`JPanel` use `FlowLayout` as default. Set to right aligning components for that with help of [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#FlowLayout-int-).

2)`JFrame` use `BorderLayout` as default. Add your panel to it with parameter `BorderLayout.SOUTH`.

3) use`frame4.setVisible(true);` at the end of construction of GUI for avoiding artifacts.

4)use `pack()`method instead of setting size to `JFrame`.

```
JFrame frame4 = new JFrame("More things");
frame4.setResizable(true);
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>One thing more</html>");
panel.add(label); 
frame4.add(panel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
frame4.pack();
frame4.setVisible(true);
```

[image]